# What kind of integral or analysis is capable of dealing with cantor's function?

Tags: definition, lebesgue-integral

According to Lebesgue’s characterization of Riemann integrable functions (see: http://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/Lebesgue.pdf)
cantor funciton on $[0,1]$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is riemann integrable, and since it's bounded. They should be equal. However, since $f$ (the cantor function) is singular on $[0,1]$, $f'=0$ almost everywhere. Thus remmann and lebesgue both equal to $0$.

So both lebesgue and riemann integralbe can not deal with cantor's function or Weierstrass function on $[0,1]$(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

My question was what kind of analysis techniques can be used to deal with cantor funciton, or even Weierstrass function?

Comment: Technically, the Cantor function can be differentiated in the sense of distribution theory, but this is in some sense "cheating".

Comment: Are you talking about integral of $f$ or $f'$? Integral of $f$ is not zero.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Two cases, 1 $f'$ exists  almost everywhere, but obviously "did not work", second case, $f'$ does not exists at all.

Comment: What do you mean by 'deal with'? The integral of the Cantor function is ${1 \over 2}$ not $0$.

Comment: @copper.hat They are talking about the failure of (the hypotheses of) the fundamental theorem of calculus. The first part is quite nonsensical however (the Cantor function itself is indeed both Riemann and Lebesgue integrable and the integrals are the same).